# Subsetting data frame using variable with same name as column

Tags: r, for-loop, scope, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame and I'm trying to run a subset on it. In my data frame, I have a column called "start" and I'm trying to do this:

```
sub <- subset(data,data$start==14)
```

and I correctly get a subset of all the rows where start=14.

But, when I do this:

```
for(start in seq(1,20,by=1)) {
   sub <- subset(data,data$start==start)
   print(sub)
}
```

it does not correctly find the subsets. It just prints the entire data frame.

Why is this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also specify the environment you're working with:

```
x<-data.frame(
  start=sample(3,20,replace=TRUE),
  someValue=runif(20))

env<-environment()
start<-3
cat("\nDefaut scope:")
print(subset(x,start==start)) # all entries, as start==start is evaluated to TRUE

cat("\nSpecific environment:")
print(subset(x,start==get('start',env)))  # second start is replaced by its value in former environment. Equivalent to subset(x,start==3)
```

Answer (score 3):

Fixing it is easy. Just rename either your `for` loop counter or your data frame column to something other than `start`.

The reason it happens is because `subset` is trying to evaluate the expression `data$start == start` inside the data frame `data`. So it sees the column `start` and stops there, never seeing the other variable `start` you defined in the `for` loop.

Perhaps a better insight into why R gets confused here is to note that when using `subset` you don't in general need to refer to variables using `data$`. So imagine telling R:

```
subset(data,start == start)
```

R is just going to evaluate both of those `start`'s inside `data` and get a vector of all `TRUE`'s back.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use bracket subsetting rather than the `subset` function.

```
for(start in seq(1,20,by=1)) {
   sub <- data[data$start==start,]
   print(sub)
}
```

`subset` has non-standard evaluation rules, which is leading to the scoping problem you are seeing (to which `start` are you referring?).  If there are (or may be) `NA`'s in `data$start`, you probably need

```
sub <- data[!is.na(data$start) & data$start==start,]
```

Note this warning from the `subset` help page:

> This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like [, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument subset can have unanticipated consequences.