# Subsetting data.table using variables with same name as column

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I want to subset a `data.table` using a variable which has the same name as the column which leeds to some problems:

```
dt <- data.table(a=sample(c('a', 'b', 'c'), 20, replace=TRUE),
                 b=sample(c('a', 'b', 'c'), 20, replace=TRUE),
                 c=sample(20), key=c('a', 'b'))

evn <- environment()
a <- 'b'
dt[a == a]

#Expected Result
dt[a == 'b']
```

I came across [this possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572400/subsetting-data-frame-using-variable-with-same-name-as-column):

```
env <- environment()
dt[a == get('a',env)]
```

But it is as unhandy as:

```
this.a = a
dt[a == this.a]
```

So is there another elegant solution?

Comment: We're aware of this [scoping issue](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2110&group_id=240&atid=978). This is very much a priority and will be fixed ASAP. Thanks for reporting. For now, using a different variable name would be the way to go.

Comment: I'm confused - why would you think that `a == a` should work or is good syntax? R-forge seems to be down for me atm, so I can't see the link from @Arun and what exactly it's about, but making `a == a` work (in the way OP wants it to work) seems like a bad idea to me and I think your last solution *is* the correct one.

Comment: Separately from my above comment, since your `data.table` is keyed by `a`, you can do `dt[a]`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102068/keyed-lookup-on-data-table-without-with/15102156#15102156

Answer (score 13):

For now, a temporary solution could be,

```
`..` <- function (..., .env = globalenv())
{
  get(deparse(substitute(...)), env = .env)
}

..(a)
## [1] "b"

dt[a==..(a)]
##    a b  c
## 1: b a 15
## 2: b a 11
## 3: b b  8
## 4: b b  4
## 5: b c  5
## 6: b c 12
```

Though this looks elegant, I am still waiting for a more robust solution to such scope issues.

Edited according to @mnel's suggestion,

```
`..` <- function (..., .env = sys.parent(2))
{
  get(deparse(substitute(...)), env = .env)
}
```

Comment: `env=sys.parent(2)` might be safer.

Comment: @mnel A nice concern! May I ask "why" and where can I find any related documentation to read?

Comment: You may be calling `[.data.table` from something which isn't the global environment, `sys.parent(2)`, will search and find the correct calling environment.

Comment: Thanks. `sys.parent(2)` should be a more practical option!

Answer (score 10):

Now it's simple (since `..()` syntax introduced in data.table):

```
dt[eval(dt[, a %in% ..a])]
```

or even simpler in your particular case (since `a` is a 1st column):

```
dt[eval(.(a))] # identical to dt["b"]
```

Comment: Re dt[a], good idea for the OP's case of a string column, but it does not generalize. Eg, `dt2 = data.table(x = c(1,2,2), key="x"); x = 2; dt2[x]` here x is recognized as a vector of row numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your note Frank, you're right. I've replaced dt2[x] approach to dt2[eval(.(x))] to generalize.