# Use variable in i of data.table subset

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I am new to data.table and think that this is an easy question, but can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

I want to subset a table based on the value of two columns, whose names I know. But I want to compare against a value which I don't know in advance. That is, I want to use a variable for the i portion of DT[]. But I can't seem to figure out how to do it. Everything I see explains how to use a variable for j (i.e. column names), but not for i.

When I just put the name of the variable in, i.e.

```
setkey(dtpredictions, colA, colB)
nextweek = dtpredictions[J(uservar, weekvar)]
```

it returns the entire table. Trying to apply the answer to FAQ 1.6, I tried:

```
  nextweek = dtpredictions[J(eval(quote(uservar)), eval(quote(weekvar)))]
```

and

```
 nextweek = dtpredictions[J(eval(user), eval(week))]
```

but both still returned the whole table.

I am pretty sure this is very simple, but I am stuck.

**EDIT**
I apologize for not clarifying earlier: I would like to do a binary search, since I need the speedup. I know that I can do a vector scan using ==, but I would prefer not to.

Comment: Just want to confirm that `uservar` and `weekvar` are single character or numeric vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem - one of my variables had the same name as a column in the table. I actually saw a question about a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658893/subsetting-data-table-using-variables-with-same-name-as-column?lq=1), but didn't even realize that I had that issue. (It was another column in the table, not the one I was subsetting on.)

I changed the name of the variable I was using to subset and now it works.

Comment: bsg, you could maybe accept this answer, so that this remains closed..? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

hmmm...interesting. Does this code seem to work for you? I am not getting the same error. I am using `data.table 1.9.3`.

```
require(data.table)
iris <- data.table(iris)

#Create new categorical variable
set.seed(1)
iris[ , new.var := sample(letters[1:5],150,replace=TRUE)]

#Set keys
setkey(iris,Species,new.var)

#Create variables to reference
check1 <- "setosa"
check2 <- "b"

#Return matches
iris[J(check1,check2)]
```

And the resulting table:

```
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species new.var
 1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa       b
 2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa       b
 3:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa       b
 4:          5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2  setosa       b
 5:          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa       b
 6:          5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3  setosa       b
 7:          5.1         3.7          1.5         0.4  setosa       b
 8:          4.8         3.4          1.9         0.2  setosa       b
 9:          5.0         3.0          1.6         0.2  setosa       b
10:          5.2         3.5          1.5         0.2  setosa       b
11:          4.7         3.2          1.6         0.2  setosa       b
```

Comment: Your example worked on my system. And thanks to that, I worked out what the problem was - I had a column in the table with the same name as one of my variables. I read the question on this issue here on SO, and didn't even notice that I had the same problem. I hope you don't mind if I don't accept your answer, since it wasn't the problem, but thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Is this you are looking for?

```
setkey(dtpredictions, colA, colB)
nextweek <- dtpredictions[colA == uservar & colB == weekvar]
```

Comment: Doesn't that do a vector scan, rather than the binary search that is one of data.table's major benefits?

Comment: Yes, it does a vector scan. It was not specified in the question which type of scan you are looking for.

Comment: do you know how to do it by binary search?