# Column name equal to variable name

Tags: r, data.table

How can I handle this case?

```r
d <- data.table(
  a = c(1, 2, 3)
)
a <- 2
d[a == a]
```

Gives:

```r
   a
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
```

Expected result is:

```r
   a
1: 2
```

Comment: Apologies to everyone, I have found the duplicate [Subsetting data.table using variables with same name as column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21658893/3817004) *after* having posted my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've inadvertently fallen prey to this, too. This is about scoping in general, not just `data.table` (`dplyr` will do the same thing). You can find similar problems in a `function` body by defining a variable that masks the same-named variable in the parent (or global) environment.

```r
a <- 1
# a brain-dead example
myfunc <- function() {
  a <- 2
  a - a
}
```

In that `function` example, it's "obvious" that there is complete ambiguity in which `a` is which, but it is effectively the same thing in your question. At no point is it safe to assume that the LHS or RHS of the inequality is *always* inside the data, and the other is *always* outside; the search begins inside and moves outside if nothing is found. Because it is found inside on both sides of `==`, both LHS and RHS use 'inside'.

I have wondered if it would be difficult to say *"if it is found 'inside' on the LHS, then do not look 'inside' on the RHS"*, but I think that adds unnecessary complexity. Especially since searching for the variable is effectively done in R's normal variable-search, not necessarily manual code within the package-code.

Best answer? Don't do it. Workaround? One of:

```r
# this "should" always work, assuming "where" the external variable is defined
d[a == get("a", envir=parent.frame())]

# this only works if it is truly in the global environment
d[a == get("a", envir=globalenv())]

# and @nicola's suggestion:
d[a == evalq(a, envir=parent.frame())]
```

Comment: Also `d[a==evalq(a,envir=parent.frame())]` might be added to the list.

Comment: `get("a", pos = 1L)]` or `get("a", 1L)` are shortcuts to `get("a", envir=parent.frame())`.

Comment: Note that `get("mean", ...)` returns the function. So in case your column name also clashes with a function you have to resort to `get("mean", mode = x, ...)` whereas x has to match `typeof("mean")`. On the other hand you might be advised to avoid such clashes anyhow.

Answer (score 3):

There are two alternative solutions to this issue: The `..` symbol prefix and using `setkey()`.

For testing, a more sophisticated sample dataset is used where the value `2` of `a` is *not* located in row 2:

```
library(data.table)
d <- data.table(rn = 1:4, a = c(1, 4, 3, 2)) # a more subtle test case
a <- 2

d
```

> ```
>    rn a
> 1:  1 1
> 2:  2 4
> 3:  3 3
> 4:  4 2
> ```

#### The `..` symbol prefix

According to [data.table NEWS on version 1.10.2 (Jan 2017)](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#new-features-6):

> When `j` is a symbol prefixed with `..` it will be looked up in calling
>   scope and its value taken to be column names or numbers.

Unfortunately, this currently is only available for the `j=` parameter but not for the `i=` parameter. (According to [data.table NEWS on version 1.11.0, May 2018, new features item 18](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#new-features-5) this might be expanded to symbols appearing in `i=` and `by=`, too.)

However, we can use this to create a vector of logical values or a vector of indices which can be used for subsequent subsetting:

```
library(magrittr)
d[, a == ..a] %>% d[.]
```

> ```
>    rn a
> 1:  4 2
> ```

or

```
d[, .I[a == ..a]] %>% d[.]
```

> ```
>    rn a
> 1:  4 2
> ```

For subsetting, `magrittr` style *piping* is used as the `..` symbol prefix is not yet implemented to be used in `i=`. Thus, using  `d[, a == ..a]` directly as `i=` parameter, i.e., `d[i = d[, a == ..a]]` will not work (it returns `d` unsubsetted).

#### `setkey()`

For the less general use case of filtering `d` by the local variable `a`, `setkey()`
can be used:

```
setkey(d, a)
d[a]
```

> ```
>    rn a
> 1:  4 2
> ```

#### `get("a", pos = 1L)`

`get("a", pos = 1L)]` or even shorter `get("a", 1L)` is an abbreviation of `get("a", envir=parent.frame()` which already has been suggested in [r2evans' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57856144/3817004).

`get("a", 1L)` is somehow equivalent to `..a` but is more robust as it can be used directly in `i=`:

```
d[a == get("a", 1L)]
```

> ```
>    rn a
> 1:  4 2
> ```