# Pass logical expression to function for data.table in R

Tags: r, function, date, data.table, arguments

I want to pass a numeric amount to a function, within which I'll use it to select rows in a data table. Here is a simple example, where the numeric amount is a date:

```
#' Example
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

test <- function(date = NULL){
  DT <- as.data.table(economics)
  if (!is.null(date)){
    date <- as.Date(date)
# See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658893/subsetting-data-table-using-variables-with-same-name-as-column
    DT <- DT[eval(DT[,date %in% ..date])] # Pick one date
  }
  DT
}
```

Note that it uses the second method recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658893/subsetting-data-table-using-variables-with-same-name-as-column) to use the same name for a function argument as a data.table column.

This works with the following call:

```
junk <- test(date = "1970-01-01")
```

Also note that in real life I won't use the dataset used in the example. Instead, I'll download UN population data from [here](https://population.un.org/wpp/Download/Files/1_Indicators%20(Standard)/CSV_FILES/WPP2019_TotalPopulationBySex.csv). This is relevant since this dataset codes dates a numeric values by year only, so there is no need to convert with as.Date(), as in the example.

So the call would look more like:

```
   junk <- test(date = 1970)
```

Here's the problem. Besides passing single values as date, I also want to pass logical expressions. But what is the best way to do this?

For convenience, let's differentiate "..date" as a reference to the date argument from "date" as a reference to the date column name.

Within the example function, the second modification to DT currently uses:

```
   DT <- DT[date %in% ..date],
```

where ..date has been converted from character to Date. Because I'm using a dataset that codes dates as numeric values, this conversion is unnecessary. (But the calling code sometimes may need to convert the numeric values to Dates.)

Now I want something like

```
   DT <- DT [date ..date],
```

where ..date could be the backend of a logical expression, such as "<= 1970".

So, in terms of a simple selection of a subset of data table, this could sometimes evaluate as:

```
   DT <- [date == 1970],
```

and other times as:

```
   DT <- [date <= 1970]
```

What's the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```r
test <- function(..., .data = data.table::as.data.table(economics)) {
  ind <- Reduce(`&`, eval(substitute(list(...)), envir = .data))
  .data[ind,]
}
```

It supports:

- single argument, an arbitrary length/complexity, that will be resolved within the context of `.data`:

  ```r
  test(date > as.Date("1969-01-01") & date < as.Date("1970-01-01"))
  #           date   pce    pop psavert uempmed unemploy
  #  1: 1969-02-01 588.7 201881     9.7     4.9     2692
  #  2: 1969-03-01 588.9 202023    10.2     4.0     2712
  #  3: 1969-04-01 593.9 202161     9.7     4.0     2758
  #  4: 1969-05-01 600.3 202331    10.1     4.2     2713
  #  5: 1969-06-01 600.9 202507    11.1     4.4     2816
  #  6: 1969-07-01 602.7 202677    11.8     4.4     2868
  #  7: 1969-08-01 609.9 202877    11.5     4.4     2856
  #  8: 1969-09-01 613.2 203090    11.6     4.7     3040
  #  9: 1969-10-01 618.5 203302    11.4     4.5     3049
  # 10: 1969-11-01 620.5 203500    11.6     4.8     2856
  # 11: 1969-12-01 622.8 203675    11.8     4.6     2884
  ```
- arbitrary number of arguments, combined with the logical vectorized `&`:

  ```r
  test(date > as.Date("1969-01-01"), date < as.Date("1970-01-01"))
  ```
- set membership (standard R)

  ```r
  test(date %in% as.Date(c("1969-04-01", "1969-07-01")))
  #          date   pce    pop psavert uempmed unemploy
  # 1: 1969-04-01 593.9 202161     9.7     4.0     2758
  # 2: 1969-07-01 602.7 202677    11.8     4.4     2868
  ```

It doesn't have a specific `date` argument, but if you're looking for various combinations of set membership, equality, or inequality, I thought it best to "make" you use `date == 1970` instead of `date = 1970` (which would be a named argument).

It might be feasible to add a named arguments `date=` that, if `!missing(date)`, would be used for set membership.

```r
test2 <- function(..., date, .data = data.table::as.data.table(economics)) {
  ind <- Reduce(`&`, eval(substitute(list(...)), envir = .data))
  if (!missing(date)) {
    stopifnot("date" %in% colnames(.data))
    ind <- ind & .data[["date"]] %in% date
  }
  .data[ind,]
}

test2(date > as.Date("1969-01-01"), date < as.Date("1970-01-01"), 
      date = as.Date("1969-07-01")) # this 'date=' is different than 'date' in line above
#          date   pce    pop psavert uempmed unemploy
# 1: 1969-07-01 602.7 202677    11.8     4.4     2868
```

but it is not clear to me how that adds any capability. (I guess it depends on your specific use.)